# What is the best practice to normalize CSS?

Tags: html, css, normalization, normalize-css

I have been looking around the internet for the best way to normalize my website CSS.

I have read about:

- Conditional Stylesheets;
- CSS Reset;
- Normalize.css;
- Initializr;
- HTML5Boilerplate;

I know that last two have a lot of other features, but they are also give you some CSS normalization.

I'm more bend to **Normalize.css**, since seems to be only and exactly what I need, but I would like to have more opinions.

Best regards!

Comment: HTML5 boilerplate does the job fine. Not sure what else you're looking for here...

Comment: Normalize.css is widely well regarded, for example, on [HTML5Doctor.com](http://html5doctor.com/html-5-reset-stylesheet/#comment-35073), so if you think it's right for you, go for it.

Comment: Thank you for the link Alohci. It was really helpful ;)

Answer (score 0, accepted):

`normalize.css` is the way to go most likely. `reset.css` is intended to strip all of the default styles completely to their bare minimum (so for example `h1` and `h2` and the rest of the headings all have the same style) while normalize.css is more of a bare-bones but functional css reset (so you still have basic style differences, e.g. font size between `h1` and `h2` and so forth).

I believe initializr and HTML5BP use implementations of normalize.css.